# Warning or info box in NetBeans 6.9: "x" is not a known variable in the current context

Tags: java, netbeans, intellisense

I'm using NetBeans IDE 6.9 (Build 201006101454), and wrote this simple Java class (that doesn't do anything):

```
public class SomeClass {
    int someInt;
}
```

The variable "someInt" shows up in green.  When I highlight and hover over it, a tool tip box appears that says:

> someInt = >"someInt" is not a known variable in the current context.<

I'm not sure what the error means, but it sounds like I'm using a variable outside of its scope -- but that can't be, because I'm just declaring it here.

The problem does not seem to affect any programs I run, but it's annoying.  And I worry that it might be a warning that I did something wrong.  I found [this similar issue](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=173083) in a previous NetBeans release, but I'm not sure if it's related.

Can anyone tell me if this should worry me, or comfort me by confirming this is just a NetBeans bug?

Comment: The linked issue is related to JavaFX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a message from the debugger. A crazy mouse has probably started the debugger ; the *current context* is the current execution context of the debugger. I think there is a red square in the middle of the toolbar ; clic with a raisonable mouse on it, and the message disapear.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb.  I did have a debugger window open and didn't even realize it.  I was working on some Swing tutorials and I forgot to exit my program when the JFrame was closed.  In addition to the one debug session, I had 15-20 instances of the program running even though I had closed all their related windows :-/